# Add content in a global table located in the beginning of the document

Tags: tables, macros, grouping

I would like to generate a global table with entries that can be added with a command. I based myself on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334131/add-content-in-a-global-table-using-a-command) post. The issue I have is that I can only display the table *after* I added all its entries. I wold like to be able to insert the completed table *before* calling all entries.

What I did so far:

```latex
% beginning of global table
\newcommand\startGlobalTable{
    \def\GlobalTable{%
    \begin{longtable}{ ll }
        \hline
        Name & Year \\
        \hline
}}

% appending element to global table
\newcommand\addGlobalTable[2]{
    \edef\GlobalTable{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{%
        \GlobalTable%
            {#1} & {#2} \\
        \hline
    }}
}

% display the global table
\newcommand\createGlobalTable{\begin{center}\GlobalTable\end{table}\end{center}}
```

Whit this setup, the global table is displayed at the end of my document:

```latex
\startGlobalTable
Some text some text
\addGlobalTable{Hello}{World}
Some different text
\addGlobalTable{Hello}{Moon}
Some final text
\createGlobalTable
```

However when writing something like this the table at the beginning is (obviously) empty:

```latex
\startGlobalTable
\createGlobalTable
Some text some text
\addGlobalTable{Hello}{World}
Some different text
\addGlobalTable{Hello}{Moon}
Some final text
```

How can I display the table in the beginning of the document containing all entries that will be added later?

Many thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: well do it like the \tableofcontents or \listoffigures: write to some external file and then read that in at the next compilation. And be careful with `\edef`. That shouldn't be use for arbitrary text.

Comment: What determines the pair of arguments of each `\addGlobalTable` directive? Are the arguments static or dynamic? Put differently, is it crucial *where* in the document the `\addGlobalTable{...}{...}` directives occur?

Comment: Yes it is, the location where `\addGlobalTable` is called is crucial.

Comment: To Ulrike, I need more than `\tableofcontents` or `\listoffigures`, my actual `\addGlobalTable` is more complex than in the question

Comment: Probably you can use the package [datatool](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) for maintaining two databases in TeX's memory: One which is created by reading a .csv-file and which contains all data created in the previous latex-run and which is used for obtaining data in the current run. Another one which is used for adding data and which is written to .csv-file at the end of the latex-run. This way you can have TeX/datatool-macros iterate on the database for reading for creating tables/longtables wherever you like. ...

Comment: ... wherever you like. I elaborated on this kind of approach in my answer to [Use LaTeX to produce parts lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592162/118714).